# How can I get ~B + AC by simplifying (~A~B)+(AC)+(A~B~C)

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

The original expression is:

> (~A~B~C)+(~A~BC)+(A~B~C)+(A~BC)+(ABC)

I could reduce it to (~A~B)+(AC)+(A~B~C) using the Uniting Law, but I need extra help to finally simplify the expression to ~B+AC

From (~A~B)+(AC)+(A~B~C) I could factor out ~B but then, there's not anything I can simplify.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(~A~B~C)+(~A~BC)+(A~B~C)+(A~BC)+(ABC) =
(~A~B)+(A~B)+(ABC) =
~B+ABC =
~B+AC
```

or, from your reduction

```
(~A~B)+(AC)+(A~B~C) =
A(C+~B~C) + ~A~B =
A(C+~B) + ~A~B =
A~B + AC + ~A~B =
~B+AC
```

Comment: What a prompt response, I really appreciate it!

Comment: btw, how can you just remove B in ~B+ABC. The same thing with ~C in A(C+~B~C) + ~A~B on the bottom reduction

Comment: Because A+~AB = A+B. Notice that if A is 1, then the result is 1; if A is 0, then the result is determined by the value of B.